# Online User count from a Discord Role

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want my Discord Bot to display the Number of Online Users of a Role as an Activity.
I can't seem to figure it out and i can't find anything on the Web.
Can someone give me example code or explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Guild.members.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) to loop through every member of the guild, then if they have that role (you can use [`GuildMember.roles.has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has)[`(Role.id)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=id) to check that) increase a counter. When you have finished your loop through the members, use the counter in your [`Client.user.setActivity()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity).
That is what you need in order to get what you want.

Try this stuff, if you still have problems post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll help you, but first you need to try yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`filter`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter):

```js
// Discord.js v12/v13 (latest version):
const count = guild.members.cache.filter(m =>
  // If the member has the role
  m.roles.cache.has('role id') &&
  // and the member is online
  m.presence.status === 'online'
).size

// Discord.js v11:
const count = guild.members.filter(m =>
  // If the member has the role
  m.roles.has('role id') &&
  // and the member is online
  m.presence.status === 'online'
).size

// Use count here:
client.user.setActivity('...')
```

To get a guild by its ID, use this:

```js
// v12/v13
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('id')
// v11
const guild = client.guilds.get('id')
```