# im trying to make a role count on a server and i dont know how to get the role count

Tags: discord.js

im new to this and i tried making a role count:
i tried this:

```
const RolesChannel = client.channels.get("649537269988065280")
  RolesChannel.setName(RolesChannel.guild.Roles + ' Roles!')
  console.log('updated ' + RolesChannel.guild.name+ '\'s Roles channel!')
```

it would name the channel: undefined Roles!

and then i tried:

```
const RolesChannel = client.channels.get("649537269988065280")
  RolesChannel.setName(RolesChannel.guild.Roles.size + ' Roles!')
  console.log('updated ' + RolesChannel.guild.name+ '\'s Roles channel!')
```

it would just crash with this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined
at SEES (C:\Users\enfri\Documents\discord bot test\!testo.js:845:53)
at processCommand (C:\Users\enfri\Documents\discord bot test\!testo.js:342:10)
at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\enfri\Documents\discord bot test\!testo.js:148:10)
at Client.emit (events.js:210:5)
at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\enfri\Documents\discord bot test\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\enfri\Documents\discord bot test\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\enfri\Documents\discord bot test\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\enfri\Documents\discord bot test\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\enfri\Documents\discord bot test\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
```

[sceenshot of the channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dZQx.png)

Comment: This may help you. It's work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51584028/online-user-count-from-a-discord-role

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51584028/online-user-count-from-a-discord-role maybe this you ask for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand why you trying to get a count of a roles from an channel when roles are a property of a guild.
If it is what you need then just get the guild id and get the size of roles in that guild.

```
let guild = clients.guilds.get("Guild id");
Console.log(guild.roles.size);
```

Comment: No problem, if it's the right answer could you check mark it to let other users know.